# jQuery: dropdown will be extended when javascript is not available

Tags: html, jquery

I have a simple JQuery code that extends dropdown on click.

But when Javascript isn't available dropdowns cannot be extended.

Is there any option how to make extended dropdowns when Javascript is not available?

**MY CODE:**

```js
$('.mainDropdownChevron').click(function() {

  var $ptag = $(this).closest('.mainDropdown').find('p');
  $('.mainDropdownChevron.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $('p.active').not($ptag).removeClass('active');

  $(this).toggleClass('active'); // for you css .chevron.active
  $ptag.toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.mainDropdownChevron {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.mainDropdownChevron.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.mainDropdown {
  margin: 24px 0;
}

p {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

img {
  max-width: 30px;
}
p.active {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDropdowns">
  <div class="mainDropdown">
    <div class="clickableMainDropdown">
      <span>Intraorálne snímky</span>
      <img loading="lazy" class="mainDropdownChevron" src="https://cdns.iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2018/240/iconmonstr-arrow-up-thin.png" alt="Checklist chevron">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p id="pDropdownService">
        Sú snímky s nízkou dávkou žiarenia, ktoré sa vkladajú do úst a za pomoci pacienta alebo držiaka sú chytené v ústach. Na zálkade veľkosti platničky zobrazujú detailne menší počet zubov.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use CSS, which can detect hovering if not clicking. By default, give the body element the class "NoJavaScript." Inside a script tag, remove that class from the body, then you can use conditional CSS that will only work if the JavaScript wasn't able to run.

It is technically possible (I think) to use CSS to detect click events and store things like the current state of the menu, but it would be much easier to simply use the :hover tag. Especially since very few people run their browsers without JS.

```js
$('body').removeClass('NoJavaScript');
```

```css
.mainDropdownChevron {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.mainDropdownChevron.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.NoJavaScript .mainDropdownChevron:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.mainDropdown {
  margin: 24px 0;
}

p {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

img {
  max-width: 30px;
}
p.active {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.NoJavaScript .mainDropdownChevron:hover p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainDropdowns">
  <div class="mainDropdown">
    <div class="clickableMainDropdown">
      <span>Intraorálne snímky</span>
      <img loading="lazy" class="mainDropdownChevron" src="https://cdns.iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2018/240/iconmonstr-arrow-up-thin.png" alt="Checklist chevron">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p id="pDropdownService">
        Sú snímky s nízkou dávkou žiarenia, ktoré sa vkladajú do úst a za pomoci pacienta alebo držiaka sú chytené v ústach. Na zálkade veľkosti platničky zobrazujú detailne menší počet zubov.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```